# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

Нужно загрузить файл на сервер(картинку).

Имею кучу полей для заполнения, заполнили и жмём **button**, он через **onclick** шлёт синхронный запрос на сервер и получает ответ, в итоге товар добавлен и отображен.

Вопрос в том, как прикреплять к товару, картинку. Если через  то нужна Форма, а мне она не нужна, у меня всё отправляет обычный **button** через **javacript(ajax)**.

На сервере папка **Images**, хотелось бы как-то туда загружать изображение.

Вот пример как я добавляю без картинки( а надо с картинкой)

```
$.ajax({
        url: EXECUTOR,
        data: "title=reizen&size=19&width=20&age=12",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
```

как здесь можно указать картинку, что бы в php-файле её отловить к примеру **is__uploaded__file**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

плагин https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 1):

Отличнейшая статья об использовании FileReader: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file