# Как сделать загрузку фото на сервер? Node.js + Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, fileupload

Пытаюсь реализовать загрузку изображения на сервер, но файл не загружается. Помогите исправить ошибку. [ссылка на проект на github](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace.git)

в этом случае   body: {}

```js
$("#addPhoto").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var photoFile = $(this).find('input[name="filePhoto"]')[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPhoto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: FormData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).then(function (response) {
        
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Фото не сохранилось', error);
    });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробую по-другому и тогда запись создается, то фото не определяется body:
   { titlePhoto: 'sdf',
     categoryPhoto: '',
     kwPhoto: '',
     descPhoto: '',
     dateInput: '' }

```js
$("#addPhoto").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var photoFile = $(this).find('input[name="filePhoto"]')[0].files[0];
   var data = preperaDataFormToAjax('addPhoto');
 


    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPhoto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).then(function (response) {
     
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Фото не сохранилось', error);
    });
});
```

Comment: все свойства ajax https://vk.com/doc161379831_462444155

Comment: спасибо, я просматривала все свойства и вроде все необходимые использовала

Comment: посмотрите вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/323278/Загрузка-файлов-на-сервер?rq=1 вроде решено

Comment: Перед тем как отправлять - убедитесь, что у Вас есть это фото. Файлы читаются долго, вполне возможно, что Вы отправляете пустой запрос

Comment: Фото точно есть. как тогда решить проблему, что бы отправлялся не пустой запрос. Добавила к посту скрин с результатом работы функции.

Comment: 500 ошибка сервера смотрите как файл принимается на сервере судя по коду ошибки именно там проблема

Answer (score -1):

Я тоже столкнулся с таким есть 2 способа простой но костыль и правильный.
Правильный. выполняй свой код внутри этого

`$('таКнопкаНаОтправку').ready(function() {
//Тут код
}`

Костыль но работает. Метод делать все махинации после нажатия кнопки сабмита и
`setTimeout(function () {
...
} 500)`

Comment: Проблема в том что картинка не успевает погрузиться но ты уже ее обрабатываешь!